# Cloudflare - IIS Request Filtering / UrlRewrite: Allow requests if a custom headers (CF-Connecting-IP) contains a value (Specific IP)

Tags: iis, cloudflare, url-rewrite-module, requestfiltering

I have situation where I want to limit access to website only when the users are connected to VPN. But the problem is that cloudlfare sends the request from a different IP rather than the actual customer IP. After searching I got to know that cloudflare sends the customer IP in `CF-Connecting-IP` header.

Now, I want to filter my request in IIS using this. I tried Request filtering and URL rewrite but it seems I am not able to configure it correctly.

If anyone knows how to achieve it, please help.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it using URL Rewrite rule.

What I did is as follows:

1. Add a new **Blank Rule**.
2. In the Match URL section
   Requested URL: Matches the pattern
   Using: Regular Expression
   Pattern: `(.*)`
3. In the conditions section -> Add a new rule -> Input: `{ALL_HTTP}` -> Check if input string: Does not match the pattern -> Pattern: `HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP:\b(1\.2\.3\.4|ip2|ip3)\b`
4. In Action section ->  Action Type: Abort Request

After applying this every non authenticated server will get 520 error and of course you can change the expression as needed.

Hope this helps someone.